# MVC Authorise not working from seeded user

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having issues with getting the Authorise function to work on a controller. I have seeded a user as follows

```
protected override void Seed(WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        if(!context.Users.Any(t => t.UserName == "markabarmi@hotmail.com"))
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "markabarmi@hotmail.com", Email = "markabarmi@hotmail.com" };
            userManager.Create(user, "passw0d!");

            context.Roles.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin" });
            context.SaveChanges();
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }

    }
```

From this I can log into the standard MVC5 application. But when I wish to put an Authorise onto a controller or ActionResult, the login will fail and I get Invalid login attempt. This is the home controller i'm adding Authorised onto.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me please :) Thanks

Comment: You have to call `context.SaveChanges();` after the `userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are not using a RoleManager since you have the UserManager part, but this is what works for me. AddToRole() will do it's own Saving so no need for context.SaveChanges():

```
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        if (!context.Roles.Any())
        {
            // Add missing roles
            var role = roleManager.FindByName("Admin");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
            role = roleManager.FindByName("DataEntry");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("DataEntry");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
            role = roleManager.FindByName("Limited");
            if (role == null)
            {
                role = new IdentityRole("Limited");
                roleManager.Create(role);
            }
        }

        if (!context.Users.Any())
        {
            var user = userManager.FindByName("admin");
            if (user == null)
            {
                var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "admin",
                    FirstName = "Admin",
                    LastName = "User",
                    Email = "xxx@xxx.net",
                    PhoneNumber = "5556667777",
                    MustChangePassword = false
                };
                userManager.Create(newUser, "Password1");
                userManager.SetLockoutEnabled(newUser.Id, false);
                userManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, "Admin");
            }
      }
```